# Gridview ControlState very large even when viewstate disabled and not using DataKeyNames

Tags: asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I have an asp:Gridview bound to an asp:ObjectDataSource. I have disabled the ViewState on the GridView, and have not set the DataKeyNames property. I have about 10 BoundFields and a few TemplateFields. These TemplateFields are not bound to server controls but to an anchor tag or to an img tag.

However, at runtime, when I switch on page tracing I see that the ControlState of the Gridview varies between 7 and 12K for displaying just 14 rows of data. (View source on the rendered page also gives a same long string in the __VIEWSTATE hidden field). I do not understand why this happens as I have enableViewState="false" on the gridview and, as said above, I am not using DataKeyNames. So, where is this Gridview ControlState coming from and is there a way to get rid of it?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Are you sure the ViewState is coming from the GridView? Have you tried disabling ViewState at the Page level instead?

Answer (score 4):

i think its normal because:
control state cannot be disabled, Control state is designed for storing a control's essential data (such as a pager control's page number) that must be available on postback to enable the control to function even when view state has been disabled

note: **By default, the ASP.NET page framework stores control state in the page in the same hidden element in which it stores view state. Even if view state is disabled** microsoft said

that mean you actually saw the data of ControlState in _ViewState field which is ok 
  because as microsoft said the ControlState of the control stored in viewstate even if you disable ViewState

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I find it strange that it needs 12K for just storing the page number and few other data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're disabling viewstate, not using any postback controls within the gridview, and not doing paging/sorting, then you're probably better off using a repeater. Repeaters don't have to be placed inside a  tag. So, the control state won't be an issue.

If you're using .net 3.5 you could also investigate using the ListView, which to me seems like a repeater / gridview hybrid.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Are you saying that the Repeater does not use controlstate? Thanks

Comment: Tim - if it uses controls that require it, then yes. On it's own it probably doesn't - but I'm not 100% sure on that. The fact that it doesn't require being inside a server side form is a good clue.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2004/07/01/472.aspx) says that control state is actually stored in the `__VIEWSTATE` in a `HybridDictionary`.

Also, these articles say that even though you can set `EnableViewState=false`, you can never turn off `ControlState` (which is the point - so clients can't break your application):

- [Control State vs. View State Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx)
- [ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)
- [ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx)