# ASP.NET Viewstate won't disable

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Site (not a Web Application).  In a page I have a GridView which I want to disable ViewState.  However, I set ViewStateMode="Disabled" on the GridView.  That still was showing a very large ViewState when I looked at "View Source" on the page when running.  Then I additionaly set  enableviewstate="False" in the master page for the form element.  Reran and still the View Source shows a large view state.  Then I added this.EnableViewState = false; in the pages Page_Init event handler (with adding the event handler to the constructor of the page).  Reran the page and it still shows a large view state.  What do I need to do to eliminate a very large viewstate in the generated page sent to the user

```
   <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="8bYImI .......
```

I have stopped and started the IIS 7 Web Server.

I am not manually storing any data in cache.  This is a simple page that only contains a GridView and some hyperlinks.

Comment: This is worse than Whack-A-Mole! The <pages> element in web.config can also enableViewState.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See other post in SO (Mentioned below) for the same issue

[ViewStateMode Disabled but still getting ViewState element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834066/viewstatemode-disabled-but-still-getting-viewstate-element)

[Gridview ControlState very large even when viewstate disabled and not using DataKeyNames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935680/gridview-controlstate-very-large-even-when-viewstate-disabled-and-not-using-datak)